# ETIMEDOUT while making http request from AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, firewall

Screenshots of Error:

[image]

It looks like there are firewall issues.

We have checked Security Group Options which seems right:

Inbound:

[image]

Outbound:

[image]

We are not able to do any http request from the AWS EC2 instance.
We are getting ETIMEDOUT error after some time interval on every request we made from our server.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check NACL options. By default all ports/protocols are disabled in a custom VPC. We have to enable both inbound and outbound rules.

Comment: Can you guide more on it. How to enable both rules ?

Answer (score 0):

NACL Outbound Rules:-
[image]

NACL Inbound Rules:-
[image]